# NSUndoManager errors with "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, swift

Working on implementing NSUndoManager within an iOS9 app. Current undo code looks like this:

```
func setActiveColorData(colorData: ColorData) {
    if colorData != activeColorData {
        print(self)
        undoManager?.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: "setActiveColorData:", object: activeColorData!)
        undoManager?.setActionName("Change color")
        print("Set undo action")

        activeColorData = colorData
    }
}
```

`ColorData` is just a simple class with three floats inside of it (hue, saturation, brightness) and some utility methods.

Everything works fine, including the shake gesture which brings up the undo prompt. But once you click undo, the app crashes and the following error:

```
2016-02-25 16:26:58.225 Color[89399:5503615] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Color.PickerViewController setActiveColorData:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa080776820'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b75e65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108159deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105b7e48d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105acb90a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105acb4b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001066b2feb -[_NSUndoStack popAndInvoke] + 261
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001066b2162 -[NSUndoManager undoNestedGroup] + 424
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000106c46813 -[UIApplication alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:] + 151
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000106f63589 -[UIAlertView _prepareToDismissForTappedIndex:] + 136
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000106f62fc7 __35-[UIAlertView _prepareAlertActions]_block_invoke50 + 53
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000106f54572 -[UIAlertController _dismissAnimated:triggeringAction:triggeredByPopoverDimmingView:] + 133
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107604eb6 -[_UIAlertControllerView _handleActionSelectionGestureRecognizer:] + 694
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010711ee73 _UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 153
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010711b4e5 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 162
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001071194e2 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 843
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001071219a0 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke904 + 79
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010712183e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 342
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010710f101 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2634
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000106ca6f8a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000106ca81c0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000106c56b66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000106c30d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105aa1a31 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a9795c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a96e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105a96828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010a416ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    27  UIKit                               0x0000000106c36610 UIApplicationMain + 171
    28  Color                               0x00000001052a2a7d main + 109
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108c9992d start + 1
    30  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've check the PickerViewController instance and the memory locations match up (from the `print(self)` line, in this case `0x7fa080776820`). Any idea why it can't invoke this selector? Or is it something else? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this same kind of crash in a photo editing app when memory is running low. When I get a memory warning, I clear the undo manager but in my case I believe this crash happens because the memory is getting deleted out from under the undo manager.

In case it's related: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/CleaningUndoStack.html